# Node.js Forever.js uptime stopped

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, forever, amazon-ec2

I'm running a node script on my EC2 instance. I 'm using [forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to run it because I'd like to run it even when I disconnect from my SSH connection.

I run:

```
forever start app.js
```

and then list running processes using:

```
forever list
```

and for `uptime` is says `STOPPED` no matter what I do.

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command             script          forever pid   id logfile                        uptime  
data:    [0] 79f1 /usr/local/bin/node app.js 17099   17100    /home/ubuntu/.forever/79f1.log STOPPED
```

Answer (score 13):

You could just run `forever logs yourfile.js` to see logs. If you need to be sure that you are seen the right logs.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I checked the log file mentioned (duh!) `/home/ubuntu/.forever/79f1.log` and that had the error.

Turns out, it was a simple path error in my app.js script. I was using a file which wasn't in the same directory from which I ran `forever start app.js`. So it actually had nothing to do with forever.js, but was a simple path error where node couldn't find a file. Thank goodness for log files!